# How can I adjust the height of a div with respect to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a task to adjust the height of a div with respect to other div.But its not working.
My code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var heightWrapper = $('#contentWrapper').height();
    $('#leftNavPanel').css('min-height', heightWrapper);
    $('#leftNavPanelSignArrow').css('min-height', heightWrapper);
});
```

Comment: You're wanting equal height columns?  Have you tried any of the pure CSS solutions?

Comment: That code will only make sure they have an equal `min-height`.

Comment: I uploaded an image.The left part is not taking full height

Comment: you have to put `px` after `heightWrapper` like this `css('min-height', heightWrapper + "px")`

Comment: No changes in the window

Comment: Anyway, it should be more coerent using `.css('height') :

var heightWrapper = $('#contentWrapper').css('height');`

cause it returns the value with 'px'.

Comment: @donkeydown `.css` gets the value of the inline style property... not the computed one http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .height() function does not consider paddings on your contentWrapper? Try to use:

```
$('#contentWrapper').outerHeight(true);
```

In addition check, if you have cleared all floating elements to get an correct block formatting context for #contentWrapper.

Answer (score -1):

Instead "min-height" try to use "minHeight". jQuery doesn't like "-" and instead use capital next character.